# Round to 2 decimals a column and giving format in Colab

Tags: python, pandas, format, google-colaboratory, percentage

I'm creating df's and I would like to round this to 2 decimals and a format % for excel so I'm strugling with this, this is my code:

```
li = []

for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    value_counts = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
    value_percentage = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame().reset_index()#.style.format('{:.2%}')
    value_percentage = (percentage*100).astype(str)+'%'
    li.append(value_counts)
    li.append(value_percentage)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=1)
```

I'm not really sure why is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(202)
    
L = ['abdef','asdfg','assfgh','asdfghj','jhgfdsa']
c = np.random.choice(L, size=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 105, size=(5, 6)), columns=c)
print (df)
   asdfghj  jhgfdsa  jhgfdsa  abdef  asdfg  asdfg
0      101      100      104    103    101    104
1      104      104      100    102    101    103
2      104      103      101    100    103    101
3      104      100      102    102    104    100
4      101      103      102    100    104    101
```

First remove `to_frame` and `reset_index` for avoid columns `index`es, for percentages use `'{:.2%}'.format` and for avoid duplicated columns names add `rename` for percentage columns:

percentage = 39
li = []

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    value_counts = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts()
    value_percentage = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts(normalize=True).apply('{:.2%}'.format)
    li.append(value_counts)
    li.append(value_percentage.rename(value_percentage.name + '_perc'))
data = pd.concat(li, axis=1)
print (data)
     asdfghj asdfghj_perc  jhgfdsa jhgfdsa_perc  jhgfdsa jhgfdsa_perc  abdef  \
100      NaN          NaN      2.0       40.00%      1.0       20.00%    2.0   
101      2.0       40.00%      NaN          NaN      1.0       20.00%    NaN   
102      NaN          NaN      NaN          NaN      2.0       40.00%    2.0   
103      NaN          NaN      2.0       40.00%      NaN          NaN    1.0   
104      3.0       60.00%      1.0       20.00%      1.0       20.00%    NaN   

    abdef_perc  asdfg asdfg_perc  asdfg asdfg_perc  
100     40.00%    NaN        NaN    1.0     20.00%  
101        NaN    2.0     40.00%    2.0     40.00%  
102     40.00%    NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN  
103     20.00%    1.0     20.00%    1.0     20.00%  
104        NaN    2.0     40.00%    1.0     20.00%
```

Last if necessary create column from index:

```
data = data.rename_axis('val').reset_index()
print (data)
   val  asdfghj asdfghj_perc  jhgfdsa jhgfdsa_perc  jhgfdsa jhgfdsa_perc  \
0  100      NaN          NaN      2.0       40.00%      1.0       20.00%   
1  101      2.0       40.00%      NaN          NaN      1.0       20.00%   
2  102      NaN          NaN      NaN          NaN      2.0       40.00%   
3  103      NaN          NaN      2.0       40.00%      NaN          NaN   
4  104      3.0       60.00%      1.0       20.00%      1.0       20.00%   

   abdef abdef_perc  asdfg asdfg_perc  asdfg asdfg_perc  
0    2.0     40.00%    NaN        NaN    1.0     20.00%  
1    NaN        NaN    2.0     40.00%    2.0     40.00%  
2    2.0     40.00%    NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN  
3    1.0     20.00%    1.0     20.00%    1.0     20.00%  
4    NaN        NaN    2.0     40.00%    1.0     20.00%
```